# How to link decoded json to uilabels in swift?

Tags: json, swift, uilabel, urlsession

I want to link the decoded `JSON` to my `UILabels` in my view. How can I do that?
the struct given below is which I have decoded below and able to print it out. But I try to link labels to those decoded data.

```
struct Details:Decodable{
    var deaths : Int
    var recovered : Int
    var active : Int
    var critical : Int
    var cases : Int
    var tests:Int
    var todayCases:Int
    var todayDeaths:Int
    var todayRecovered:Int   
}
```

I did the parsing in `viewDidLoad`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var detailData:Details!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var infected: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var active: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recovered: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var death: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalTested: UILabel!
    
    
                                //MARK: - View DID LOAD
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
                                //MARK: - BASIC EDIT
        
        title = "Neporona"
        let group = [infected,active,recovered,death,totalTested]
        for i in group{
            i!.layer.masksToBounds = true
            i!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        }
        
        
        //MARK: - JSON DECODING
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/nepal?yesterday=false") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else { return }

            
            do{
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Details.self, from: data)
                self.detailData = decoder
                print(self.detailData!)
            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update labels on `didSet` of `detailData` as below,

```
var detailData:Details! {
    didSet {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.infected.text = String(self.detailData.cases)
             self.active.text = String(self.detailData.active)
             self.recovered.text = String(self.detailData.recovered)
         }
    }
}
```